# Ionic android build prod failed in android

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

i am using ionic 2 for hybrid application development. Once i build the android application using following command.

ionic build android --prod

I am getting the following error in my console. Whats the exact issue any one please suggest.

```
ionic-app-script task: "build"
[00:15:38]  Error: ./node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/plugins/plugin.js Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read
            property 'type' of undefined at Object.getEffectiveTypeAnnotationNode
```

Following is my ionic information:

```
 Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.6.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Comment: Since this is a problem in `ionic-native` I suspect that your fastest solution would be to either try reinstalling `@ionic-native/core`  and if that doesnt work, create a new project and copy over your src directory.